# What has replaced weights?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Trying to figure out how to position items in the latest build... Many examples online indicate to use `modifier = Modifier.weight(...)`, but the option is simply not given as of the build I'm using.

I need to send a button at the bottom of the page regardless of the size of a lazy column just above it. What's the preferred way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `1.0.0-beta02` the [**`Modifier.weight`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/ColumnScope#weight) exists.

> Size the element's height proportional to its weight relative to other weighted sibling elements in the `Column`. **The parent will divide the vertical space remaining after measuring unweighted child elements** and distribute it according to this weight

Something like:

```
val itemsList = (0..60).toList()

Column {
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)){
        items(itemsList) {
            Text("Item is $it")
        }
    }
    Row( verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom) {
        Text(text = "Footer row")
    }
}
```

[image]

Otherwise you can use a `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: I appreciate the help, it turns out I was getting errors that were not related to this... Answer works just fine :)